# Uploading file inside GDrive without logging each time

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a Python script on my Rasberry Pi that should runs once every day. I want it to send some log files in my Google Drive. But on the Google Drive API, the solution I found request to manually log in to validate the action (with `credirentials.json`).

On the OAuth 2.0 Playground page of Google Developers, I found a way to use a token (following this tuto https://youtu.be/JwGzHitUVcU). But it looks like the token is only valid for one hour.

Is their a way to refresh the token, or to upload files in my drive without asking me each time if it's me? (Actually it's a private drive I created only for that project).

Thanks in advance for your help

EDIT
Code 1 without token (this one create a file from scratch):

```py
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()

drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

file1 = drive.CreateFile({'title': 'Hello.txt'})
file1.SetContentString('Hello')
file1.Upload() # Files.insert()
```

Code 2 with token (I replaced the token string by `$TOKEN$`, and log is a string with the file name) :

```py
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer $TOKEN$"}
para = {
    "name": log,
    "parents": ["1La3s6-5jWzMOeOXDV-KAiudqMZ61BZvH"]
}
files = {
    'data': ('metadata', json.dumps(para), 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'),
    'file': open(os.path.join(cst.LOG_FOLDER_ARCHIVE, log), "rb")
}
r = requests.post(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart",
    headers=headers,
    files=files
)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.  Tips: Check out either offline access with a refresh token or service accounts.

Comment: Sorry for forgetting the code! I edited the message

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want offline access to Drive for file uploads, and you want to know more about token refreshing. If I understood the situation correctly, you only need to give an eye to this guide about [OAuth 2.0 for Desktop Apps](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app), especially the part about [refreshing access tokens](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app#offline). Please, ask me any doubts about this approach.